# How to make autocomplete in wpf textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is the code I am using for search, it returns a value when we type a whole name, but I need a  autocomplete textbox, that shows suggestions as I type a partial name.

```
private void textBox3_KeyUp_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)//Name Search
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select [Patient ID],[Patient Name],[Gender],[StudyDateTim],[Modality],[Study Name] From RepView Where [Patient Name] like '%" + textBox3.Text + "%'";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: You don't need `ExecuteNonQuery` in your case. And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use _using statement_ to dispose your database connections.

Comment: @SonerGönül:But that i dont knw how to code

Comment: @Ramji21: learn to code in this case. My intent is not to be hard, but don't expect to create good program if you don't have a minimal understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: That is a lot of database trips.  Bring down a list once and filter in .NET.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can also add the `AutoCompleteBox` into the toolbox by clicking on it and then Choose Items, go to WPF Components, type in the filter `AutoCompleteBox`, which is on the `System.Windows`

Comment: Sorry , but there is no AutoCompleteBox under WPF Components .

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `AutoCompleteTextBox` by using a simple `textbox` control and a `listbox` control. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/autocomplete-textbox-in-wpf/) which will guide you through the whole process.

But if you don't want to create it yourself so you can just use an already created control by someone else. Download it from [here](http://wpfautocomplete.codeplex.com/).

And here is the [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801004/WPF-AutoComplete-TextBox) teaching you how to use that control.